# Very specific tree traversal method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree, traversal

I've been trying to develop/find a very specific way to traverse a tree structure. I am really only familiar with the 2~3 most often used tree traversal methods, and I don't know enough jargon to effectively search the web, so please forgive me if I'm asking something very obvious or basic.

I have the following tree structure (not necessarily a binary tree):

[image: Tree structure]
<sub>(source: [renebokhorst.com](http://renebokhorst.com/stackoverflow/ProblemTree.png))</sub>

Assume I enter the tree at node "AAA". I would want the method to traverse its underlying nodes using a top down method first.

[image: Tree structure]
<sub>(source: [renebokhorst.com](http://renebokhorst.com/stackoverflow/ProblemTree2.png))</sub>

However after this, I would want the method to move up the tree, and deal with everything top down below it EXCEPT the part it already did before it.

[image: Tree structure]
<sub>(source: [renebokhorst.com](http://renebokhorst.com/stackoverflow/ProblemTree3.png))</sub>

I want it to keep doing this until it reaches the top node and finishes.

[image: Tree structure]
<sub>(source: [renebokhorst.com](http://renebokhorst.com/stackoverflow/ProblemTree4.png))</sub>

A very specific requirement is that we cannot "skip" nodes. Entering, or returning into a node has to be done from either it's parent or child. Before entering a node I also register whether the visitor is traversing up or down the tree (this is necessary information for some visitors). I can similarly also raise flags whether we are entering the tree for the first time, or whether we are passing by the entry node again. The visitor may not visit any node twice except for the entry node, which it may pass multiple times as long as the RE_ENTRY flag is raised. Ideally I do not want to keep track of a list of nodes I already passed in the past.
Now I have tried a few different approaches

```
case GLOBAL_SPREAD:
{
    if ( pVisitor->LastVisited == NULL )
        pVisitor->VisitDirection = ENTRY;

    pVisitor->visit(this);
    for ( uint32 i(0) ; i < Children.size() ; i += 1 )
    {
        pVisitor->VisitDirection = DOWN;
        Children[i]->Accept(pVisitor);
    }

    break;
}
```

This piece of code of course does nothing else than perform a top down traversal of everything below the starting node. The problems arise when I tried to add code that would bump the visitor up the tree and do a top down traversal from there. Calling Parent->Accept(pVisitor) before visiting the children obviously would not produce the desired results. Calling Parent->Accept(pVisitor) after visiting the children would only produce the desired results in the case of the entry node. For every other node it would cause problems.

I was wondering if anybody had any experience with these types of tree traversal methods, and whether I actually have enough information to do this kind of traversal at all. Again it is important that I do not keep track of any lists of previously visited items. At best I can keep track in the function itself which node was previously visited. Perhaps this is a well known and widely documented traversal method that I just don't know the name of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So basically a depth first search, except you don't necessarily start at the root node of the tree?  Seems like it would be a pretty simple modification of DFS to do that...

Comment: Do you get given a pointer to the node (AAA in the example) and have to work the tree given just that node, or are you given the root node and the starting value, and you first search the tree for the value, then do the DFS from the value, then the modified DFS for the rest of the tree?  It matters because if you're only given a pointer to the node, then you must also have a pointer-to-parent node to be able to backtrack up the tree (and you have to decide whether the root's parent node is null or itself). Is there a field in the nodes that can be used to mark 'visited'? How big are the trees?

Comment: Also, what constitutes a 'traverse up'?  Is it when you finish a DFS at a level and need to step up to the parent? If so, the only 'traverse up' cases would be moving from AAA to AA, and from AA to A?  Given the this isn't a binary tree necessarily, how do you represent the nodes at a given level?  Despite all these questions, it seems like a fairly straight-forward exercise in tree traversal.  Presumably, the search sequence for starting at ABA is: ABA, ABAA, ABAB, AB, ABB, ABBA, ABBB, A, AA, AAA, AAAA, AAAB, AAB, AABA, AABB.

Comment: @wallacer: your analysis is correct, however it breaks down shortly after having to implmenet the pretty simple modification :)

Comment: @Jonathan: You are given only the starting node. Every node has the following members { Actor Parent; Actor[] Children; void Accept(IVisitor); }. The Root can be identified using 3 methods: (1) its Parent is NULL, (2) it is of type "Root : Actor" and can have its own implementation of the function, (3) it is retrievable at any time with Root::getRoot(). 
The trees can range from small to enormous. It is for the latter limit that I do not want to keep a list of previously visited nodes. Another reason is because the code is only a small part of a routine that has to execute 60 times per second.

Comment: @Jonathan: Basically every time I move up the tree I make sure to set the traversal direction to "UP", and when I move down the tree I set the traversal direction to "DOWN". Some visitor need to transform their data depending on how the tree is traversed. Moving up the tree give different transformations within a node than moving down the tree. So yes, only when going from AAA to AA and from AA to A would constitute as moving up. Everything else as moving down.
Your analysis is correct: I would want to move in exactly the order you describe. However nothing I try produces the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to implement what you request.  The key to this working is that visiting the first node (whatever that is) is considered an `UP` operation.  The `print_tree()` and `print_preorder()` functions implement a normal preorder traversal of a tree; they're used to show that the data structure is in the correct shape.  The `dfs_traversal()` and `dfs_traverse()` functions implement your special DFS traversal.  The test code tests two specific examples (the `AAA` and `A` nodes), and then does an exhaustive check of the traversal from every node in the tree.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_CHILD = 2 };
enum { UP = 1, DOWN = 2 };
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    char    name[8];
    int     number;
    Node   *parent;
    Node   *child[MAX_CHILD];
};

static Node data[] =
{
    { "A",     0,        0, { &data[ 1], &data[ 2], }, },
    { "AA",   -3, &data[0], { &data[ 3], &data[ 4], }, },
    { "AB",   +3, &data[0], { &data[ 5], &data[ 6], }, },
    { "AAA",  -4, &data[1], { &data[ 7], &data[ 8], }, },
    { "AAB",  +4, &data[1], { &data[ 9], &data[10], }, },
    { "ABA",  -4, &data[2], { &data[11], &data[12], }, },
    { "ABB",  +4, &data[2], { &data[13], &data[14], }, },
    { "AAAA",  0, &data[3], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "AAAB", +5, &data[3], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "AABA", -5, &data[4], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "AABB", +5, &data[4], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "ABAA", -5, &data[5], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "ABAB", +5, &data[5], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "ABBA", -5, &data[6], {         0,         0, }, },
    { "ABBB", +5, &data[6], {         0,         0, }, },
};
enum { NUM_NODES = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

static void visit(Node *node, int up_down)
{
    printf("%4s: ", up_down == UP ? "UP" : "DOWN");
    printf(" %5s [%2d] N = %p; P = %p\n", node->name, node->number,
            (void *)node, (void *)node->parent);
}

static void print_tree(Node *node)
{
    if (node != 0)
    {
        visit(node, DOWN);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILD; i++)
            print_tree(node->child[i]);
    }
}

static void print_preorder(const char *tag, Node *node)
{
    printf("Tree starting from %s:\n", tag);
    print_tree(node);
}

static void dfs_traverse(int up_down, Node *node, Node *skip)
{
    if (node != 0 && node != skip)
    {
        visit(node, up_down);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHILD; i++)
            dfs_traverse(DOWN, node->child[i], skip);
        if (node->parent != 0 && up_down == UP)
            dfs_traverse(UP, node->parent, node);
    }
}

static void dfs_traversal(const char *tag, int up_down, Node *node, Node *skip)
{
    printf("DFS starting from %s\n", tag);
    dfs_traverse(up_down, node, skip);
}

int main(void)
{
    Node *aaa = &data[3];
    Node *root = &data[0];

    print_preorder("root", root);
    print_preorder("aaa",  aaa);

    dfs_traversal("aaa",  UP, aaa,  0);
    dfs_traversal("root", UP, root, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NODES; i++)
        dfs_traversal(data[i].name, UP, &data[i], 0);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
Tree starting from root:
DOWN:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
Tree starting from aaa:
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DFS starting from aaa
  UP:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from root
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from A
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AA
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AB
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from AAA
  UP:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AAB
  UP:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from ABA
  UP:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from ABB
  UP:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from AAAA
  UP:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AAAB
  UP:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AABA
  UP:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from AABB
  UP:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
  UP:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
DFS starting from ABAA
  UP:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from ABAB
  UP:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from ABBA
  UP:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DFS starting from ABBB
  UP:   ABBB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab270; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:    ABB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab130; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABBA [-5] N = 0x10dbab248; P = 0x10dbab130
  UP:     AB [ 3] N = 0x10dbab090; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    ABA [-4] N = 0x10dbab108; P = 0x10dbab090
DOWN:   ABAA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1f8; P = 0x10dbab108
DOWN:   ABAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab220; P = 0x10dbab108
  UP:      A [ 0] N = 0x10dbab040; P = 0x0
DOWN:     AA [-3] N = 0x10dbab068; P = 0x10dbab040
DOWN:    AAA [-4] N = 0x10dbab0b8; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AAAA [ 0] N = 0x10dbab158; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:   AAAB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab180; P = 0x10dbab0b8
DOWN:    AAB [ 4] N = 0x10dbab0e0; P = 0x10dbab068
DOWN:   AABA [-5] N = 0x10dbab1a8; P = 0x10dbab0e0
DOWN:   AABB [ 5] N = 0x10dbab1d0; P = 0x10dbab0e0
```

Comment: Your implementation is correct so I will reward you the points. I also came up with an implementation where I had to pass on a Node pointer to "Skip". I posted the question here because I was hoping there was a standard way of doing it without introducing helping parameters. There seems to be no way around this. Although I used OO and polymorphism, the function implementation is almost exactly thesame.

Comment: Thanks. The primary alternative to the 'skip' parameter would be a flag field in each node of the tree. The trouble with that, though, is you'd have to scan the entire tree once to set it to 'unvisited'; then you'd have to set it in each node as you visit it. That is messier than the skip parameter. Or you could use a list of nodes visited, which could easily end up with quadratic behaviour as you search it to see whether the node you're planning to visit has already been visited. The skip parameter is as clean as I can think of; it avoids modifying the data structure itself.